# getenv("ANYSTRING") is causing an internal server error

Tags: php, mod-fcgid

For some reason getenv("ANYSTRING") is causing an internal server error.  getenv() without any arguments returns an array of environment variables as expected.  I am running PHP 7.1.13 x86 Thread Safe using mod_fcgid on Apache Lounge VC15 2.4.27 (Win32) in Windows 10 x64.

I cannot simply use getenv() as this code is part of the composer framework and therefore I would rather not modify it (in EventDispatcher.php).

It appears that this is related to Bug #75794 and #75761, as adding the second parameter (local_only) to true resolves the crash, whereas setting this parameter to false or omitting it entirely causes the crash to reoccur.

Anyone have any thoughts on how to get around this issue?

Comment: An Internal Server Error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: According to the PHP documentation, passing in a string representing an environment variable, regardless of whether or not it exists, should not cause an issue. Non-existent variables should cause the value `false` to be returned. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php Odds are that you have subsequent code that's attempting to perform an invalid operation on the return value you're receiving (e.g. an array operation on a string). We can only speculate, however, because you've not provided errors or code. Please review your server's error logs in order to narrow down your issue.

Comment: The error log for Apache is unhelpful.  It throws an "End of script output before headers" error because php crashed before generating any output.  I  am having a hard time figuring out how to get PHP to spit out an error log when using FCGI.  Setting error_log = "my_path", error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT, and display_errors = 1 in .user.ini in the php script's path doesn't seem to be generating any error log at "my_path"

Comment: There isn't any subsequent code.  I can execute that statement AND ONLY that statement and crash the service.

Comment: I can generate the internal server error with a file as simple as:

Comment: <?php getenv('PATH');

Comment: There is nothing written to the php error logs from the crash.  I have verified that the log is correctly setup as <?php error_log('HELLO WORLD') ?> shows in this particular log.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is related to Bug #75794 and #75761, as adding the second parameter (local_only) to true resolves the crash, whereas setting this parameter to false or omitting it entirely causes the crash to reoccur.

To fix the issue, use the patch [here](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=commit;h=2b7d283cc5589077d7ecc23cc9b2827759cab5c2) and rebuild your version of php, or use a different version of PHP altogether (7.0.x or 7.2.x).

Comment: Moreover, the latest snapshot of 7.1.13 released yesterday, January 16, fixes the bug as well.  It is available here: http://windows.php.net/snapshots/